# Ruby Module self.class and class_inheritable_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain to me what this would do?

```ruby
Module Foo
  class Bar
    class_inheritable_accessor :foobar
    def foobar
      self.class.foobar
    end
  end
end
```

I wish I could be more clear, but I have no idea what this does. I found it in a piece of code I am working with.

I do not see any other definition of `foobar` anywhere else. So what exactly is the method referencing? Itself?

It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class inheritable accessors allow classes to override class variables down the hierarchy.

I thought `class_inheritable_accessor` *already* defined a class variable getter that reads from the inheritable attribute hash. The example you show seems to bypass it for `foobar`, so it's not clear to me what the original intent was--can you show more context?

See [here for a nice discussion](http://www.raulparolari.com/Rails/class_inheritable).

Comment: Sorry Dave, the code is way too big for me to parse down for context. But working off your explaination. If somewhere else in the code, self.foobar = "Hi" -- Does that mean the class_inheritable_accessor allows me to receive "Hi" through self.class.foobar?

Comment: @vinhboy Yes, because `class_inheritable_accessor` creates a getter/setter for the class variable. The getter is overridden, which is what I don't quite get.

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question. I agree with you. I don't understand why they overwrote the getter either. It really confused the crap out of me. I removed it, and everything seems to work normally. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @vinhboy No problem. Yeah, I had to re-read that link a few times and stared at your code for awhile before admitting it confused me :/ Only thing I can think of is that it might matter in a deeper hierarchy.